# How to order data by relationship in laravel with paginatation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

This is my table.i need all post in descending order.I want advertised posts in top.

[image]

result example

[image]

Code

```
$data=Post::get();
```

Relationship in model

```
public function isAdvertised()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\models\PostAdvertise', 'post_id');
    }
```

Comment: add code of controller

Comment: @JinalSomaiya just added code.

Comment: Please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52295503/5013099

Answer (score 1):

You can use leftJoin

```
$data = Post::leftJoin('post_advertise', 'post.id', '=', 'post_advertise.post_id')
    ->orderBy('post_advertise.created_at')
    ->select('post.id', 'post.title', 'post.description')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$posts = Post::with('isAdvertised')->all();
$sorted_posts = $posts->sortBy(function ($post, $key) {
    return (is_null($post->isAdvertised) ? 1 : 0);
});
```

This will order the collection.

Comment: I want collection in paginate also not in get or all.

Answer (score -1):

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

You can then add this to your view:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    $post->post_advertise->title
@endforeach
```

If it does not work I would advise you to post exactly what you did, like your migration, model(relationship) and controller.